# repeticiones en SQL server

Tags: sql-server

¿Como puedo hacer para que el siguiente Script me ejecute un Proc, la cantidad de veces que esta insertada la columna?

```
CREATE TABLE #tabletemp (Escala INT)
INSERT #tabletemp VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);
DECLARE 
@Escala varchar (1),
@Escala1 INT

SET @Escala  = (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #tabletemp)
SET @Escala1 = (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #tabletemp ORDER BY Escala DESC)
    WHILE (@Escala1) < 3
        BEGIN
        EXEC PS_GameLog.dbo.TEST
        @Escala
        END
 DROP TABLE #tabletemp
```

el Proc almacenado es el siguiente:

```
USE [PS_GameLog]
ALTER  Proc [dbo].[TEST]
@Escala varchar (1)
AS
PRINT 'TEST de Prueba Numero (' + @Escala+ ') Cantidad de veces.'
```

Comment: Puedes colocar la tabla TEST?

Comment: NO es una tabla es un Procedimiento almacenado amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución, es leer con la función count el número de registros que tiene la tabla temporal, y después ejecutar un bucle. 
Pero como el parámetro que recibe es un varchar, realizar un cast en una variable auxiliar.
En cada vuelta del bucle, tienes que decrementar en uno el número de registros leídos.

```
CREATE TABLE #tabletemp (Escala INT)
INSERT #tabletemp VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);

DECLARE @COUNT INT;
SELECT @COUNT=COUNT(*) FROM #TABLETEMP;
DECLARE @COUNT_VARCHAR VARCHAR(1);

    WHILE (@COUNT) > 0
        BEGIN
           SET @COUNT_VARCHAR = CAST(@COUNT AS VARCHAR(1));
           EXEC dbo.TEST @COUNT_VARCHAR
           SET @COUNT -=1;
        END
 DROP TABLE #tabletemp
```

La ejecución del mismo, produce esta salida.

```
(3 filas afectadas)
TEST de Prueba Numero (3) Cantidad de veces.
TEST de Prueba Numero (2) Cantidad de veces.
TEST de Prueba Numero (1) Cantidad de veces.
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto estimado:

```
CREATE TABLE #tabletemp (Escala INT)

INSERT #tabletemp 
VALUES (1),
        (2),
        (3);

DECLARE @Escala int

select @Escala = MIN (Escala) from #tabletemp

while exists(select top 1 1 from #tabletemp where Escala >= @Escala)
begin
    EXEC dbo.TEST @Escala=@Escala

    select  @Escala = MIN (Escala) from #tabletemp where Escala > @Escala
end

DROP TABLE #tabletemp
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], una explicación no caería mal